# Symfony2 Form with collection type (many-to-many)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-odm

### What I have

I have a database table "**Teams**" and a table "**Players**", connected with a Teams_has_Players table (many-to-many relationship). I generated my entities. I can now succesfully retrieve the players from a team by doing: `$players = $team->getPlayers()->toArray();`

### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to make a form where you can edit all of the team's player **names** and their **position** on the field. So I basically would like to have some rows with in each row an input field with the name and an input field with his location.

### What I tried to do

So I read a lot about the Symfony2 Collection type and tried this:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(null)
    ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name', 'data' => $team->getName()))
    ->add('players', 'collection', array('data' => $team->getPlayers()->toArray()))
    ->getForm();
```

In my view I tried this:

```
<ul>
    {% for player in form.players %}

        <li>
            {{ form_widget(player.name) }}{{ form_widget(player.position) }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But I get this error:

> The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an
>   instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class
>   MatchTracker\Bundle\AppBundle\Entity\Players. You can avoid this error
>   by setting the "data_class" option to
>   "MatchTracker\Bundle\AppBundle\Entity\Players" or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms an instance of class
>   MatchTracker\Bundle\AppBundle\Entity\Players to scalar, array or an
>   instance of \ArrayAccess.

So I added `'data_class' => 'MatchTracker\Bundle\AppBundle\Entity\Players'`, but then I get an error that The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class MatchTracker\Bundle\AppBundle\Entity\Players, but is a(n) array. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null

Anyone that can help me solve this problem? I just want to edit the team's player names/locations/.. in a form. If that works I'm going to extend the form so I can [add/remove players](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/collection.html#adding-and-removing-items).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is what your are trying to do.](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: Can't believe that I overlooked this! Thanks, worked instantly